# How to create vb.net advance autoupdate class

Tags: vb.net, exe, auto-update

How would I create a class that would load on Window_load in order to check web address (myapp.exe) for new updates and download updated myapp.exe (while user is still using application). Once downloaded, prompt user to close application in order to run updated version of myapp.exe ? If user chooses to run updated version later then how would I make sure the old version of myapp.exe was deleted and they were using new version of myapp.exe, once they closed myapp.exe?

Any suggestions would help!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggesst searching for "Click-once". This sounds very similar.